# UpdateProgress not working with AssociatedUpdatePanelID

Tags: asp.net, updatepanel, updatepanel-progressbar

I cannot get the update progress to work at all, here is my code:

```
<asp:ScriptManager runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
     <asp:UpdateProgress ID="updProgress" AssociatedUpdatePanelID="myUpdatePanel" runat="server">
            <ProgressTemplate>           
                 <div class=".uk-icon-spin"></div>  Processing...           
            </ProgressTemplate>
     </asp:UpdateProgress>
<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="myUpdatePanel">
     <ContentTemplate>
          <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Panel created."></asp:Label><br />
          <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" OnClick="Button1_Click" Text="Create Instance" />
     </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Does anyone know what could be causing it? Thanks

Comment: I never used UpdateProgress myself, but for some reason all examples found for it on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398821.aspx) have `UpdateMode="Conditional"` on all update panels for some reason. Can you try the same out?

Comment: ok, the issue seems to be because the page with the update panel in is being loaded by jQuery AJAX. The code triggers for the OnClick method, server side but the update panel does not work. If I access the page directly it is fine... anyway around this?

Comment: So yes, i can see how can this be an issue, since when you load page via jquery you probably do not run all the JS stuff that is supposed to run on startup. How exactly are you loading this page?